# What can glass be used for?

Tags: terraria

What are some things that can be crated with the item 'glass' in the game Terraria and what are their uses?

Comment: give some glass to the guide?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the following link for the different ways to use glass.

http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Glass

[image]

The gamepdia for Terraria pretty much covers everything about crafting so if you have any questions of "how to craft __" or "what can I use __ for" I would check there first for the answer.

Comment: Another good idea is to check with the guide's crafting dialog.

Answer (score 3):

Glass can be used for a number of things it can

- Be placed as a block
- made into backgorund wall
- crafted into a number of glass items like "bottles" to hold water

When glass is placed as a block it lets light in while keeping mobs out